# uenc in the url

Tags: magento-1.9, url

We are migrating a project, after migrating code to new server, 
at the cart page the product removing is not working (http://35.185.190.192/checkout/cart/delete/id/61137/uenc/aHR0cDovLzM1LjE4NS4xOTAuMTkyL2NoZWNrb3V0L2NhcnQv/).

**when i remove the uenc from the URL** it removes the product(http://35.185.190.192/checkout/cart/delete/id/61137/),

what is the cause producing this issue, what is the use/need of **uenc** parameter,?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this.

https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/wtf-is-uenc

solution

https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/1058

redirect has not encoded url.

Answer (score 1):

UENC stands for "URL encoded". If you take the encoded string and base64 decode it, then you will see the actual result.

So "**aHR0cDovLzM1LjE4NS4xOTAuMTkyL2NoZWNrb3V0L2NhcnQv**" is the encoded string of "http://35.185.190.192/checkout/cart/"

You can decode the string on sites like [this](https://www.base64decode.org/).

More infos can be found [here](https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/wtf-is-uenc), or google "What is UENC ?" If the link dies one day.